# How to insert/update information in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert new information into my already created table where id = 2019;

I get the error incorrect syntax near `WHERE`:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xcon.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter xadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    xadapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT into dbo.SysX VALUES (@fpp, @sdd, @sff) WHERE id = 2019", xcon);
    xadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@fpp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    xadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@sdd", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    xadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@sff", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

    xadapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    xcon.Close();
}
```

How can I insert new information on click of button where ID = 2019?

Comment: You cannot do `WHERE` without `UPDATE`/`SELECT` clause. Either remove `WHERE` clause or use `UPDATE` for existing record.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks. why wont this work?

Comment: @Ryze2 it is because you are writing wrong syntax of SQL Server.

Comment: If you would only [check the *official documentation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) from Microsoft on the `INSERT` statement, you could easily see there is no `WHERE` clause supported for the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the below line

```
xadapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT into dbo.SysX VALUES (@fpp, @sdd, @sff) WHERE id = 2019", xcon);
```

to the as below line if you want to insert value/row into the table.

```
xadapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT into dbo.SysX VALUES (@fpp, @sdd, @sff)", xcon);
```

If you want to update existing record then you need to replace your SQL Statement as

```
"Update dbo.SysX Set <Col1> = @fpp, <Col2> = @sdd, ... where id = 2019"
```

You can check this [Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/164110) and [this link](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

INSERT and UPDATE are two really separate SQL commands. As their name suggests, with INSERT you *add* new record to a table, with UPDATE you *edit* existing record, so either you provide a pointer to an existing record to edit it

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = data WHERE Field = ‘x’
```

or you just provide a number of values to be inserted

```
INSERT INTO Table (Columns) VALUES (Data)
```

On a side note, such insertions or updates are best done with stored procedures, in order to avoid sql injection attacks.